# Access 2010 VBA Loop query until query is null

Tags: sql, vba

I've been using Access for about a year now, and have only recently begun learning about VBA.  The books I've read and the help I've read online don't seem to fit quite what I need; or if they do, then I must be too much of a novice to notice.

My project is a personal financial database, and I'm working on a way to forecast cash flows.  I've got

1. a table with recurring transactions called 'tbl_InitialPoint'
       (with columns Description, Amount, and Frequency (in days)),
2. a query that finds the last date of a particular Description in
       'tbl_Register',
3. an append query to insert recurring transactions from 'tbl_InitialPoint' to 'tbl_Register'

   INSERT INTO tbl_Register ( PostDate, Description, Amount ) SELECT qry_MaxDate.LastDate + tbl_InitialPoint.Frequency AS DateSeries, tbl_InitialPoint.Description, tbl_InitialPoint.Amount
   FROM tbl_InitialPoint INNER JOIN qry_MaxDate ON tbl_InitialPoint.Description = qry_MaxDate.Description
   WHERE qry_MaxDate.LastDate + tbl_InitialPoint.Frequency <= [Forms]![HomePage]![DateHorizon];

What I have no idea about is the specific vba to run/loop this query x number of times until the query is null or empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose here that you are using local Access tables and the corresponding DAO objects.

You'l have to use the `queryDef` object and its `execute` method.

Once the querydef executed, you can then test the `recordsAffected` property of your `queryDef` instance.

If this value is equal to zero, this will mean that no records have been inserted through your query.

EDIT: following your comments, you can see some `queryDef` related code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177500%28v=office.12%29.aspx) , where you'll be able to create a new querydef and list the properties of the object, including the `recordsAffected` property.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not getting it.  Could you give me an example of what the code might look like.  I've tried several times using what you described above, and I can't even get my named queryDef to execute once.

Comment: Here's what I have so far (I can add the loop later):Private Function InsertTransactionsBttn_Click()

    Dim db As Database
    Dim MySQL As String
    Dim qdfNew As QueryDef

Comment: Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set MySQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_Register ( PostDate, Description, Amount )" & _
        "SELECT qry_MaxDate.LastDate + tbl_InitialPoint.Frequency AS DateSeries, tbl_InitialPoint.Description, tbl_InitialPoint.Amount" & _
        "FROM tbl_InitialPoint INNER JOIN qry_MaxDate ON tbl_InitialPoint.Description = qry_MaxDate.Description" & _
        "WHERE qry_MaxDate.LastDate + tbl_InitialPoint.Frequency <= [Forms]![HomePage]![DateHorizon]"
    Set qdfNew = CreateQueryDef("NewQueryDef", _
        MySQL)
    
        qdfNew.Execute

End Function